# Debugging tools for javascript to clean unused variables, syntax errors ....

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have Findbugs, PMD tools for debugging java source code. Any other tools for finding bugs in javascript or jQuery source code.?

Comment: Found a solution to find some errors. we can use jshint or jslink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is the best debugging tool for client side scripts.

1. we can inspect and edit elements.
2. we can visualize css metrics.
3. monitor networking.
4. debug and profile javascipt

and many other things. It's simply becomes best tool for debugging.

For more info : http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug

Answer (score 2):

For actively debugging Javascript, Firebug is my favorite.  It allows you to set breakpoints within the script and inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use into your web browser [FireBug](https://www.getfirebug.com/), it works on Chrome, Mozilla.
You can add multiple firebug extension like [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) for Jquery developement, [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) for CRUD on cookie, etc.